# pipe fzf selection to text manipulation to zsh prompt (without executing)

Tags: zsh, fzf

Here's a function that executes a selected alias using fzf:

```
fa() { 
  eval $(alias | fzf | cut -d'=' -f2 | sd -p "'" '') 
}
```

The problem is that sometimes you want to add more arguments to an alias rather than immediately execute it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using zsh:

```
fa() { 
  print -z $(alias | fzf | cut -d'=' -f2 | sd -p "'" '') 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `print -z` interfers with _sed_ command. For example, escaping special characters, such as `'` or `(`, with _sed_ no longer works. It would have been easier if _fzf_ offered a way to print selected items onto the prompt only.

Comment: As a workaround, I had to use a combination of `awk '{printf "%s ", $0}'` (to convert multi-line into single line) and _pbcopy_ (to copy formatted output to clipboard). Then, manually pasting with ^V (or ⌘V).

Comment: I think you're assuming sd means sed? sd is different and doesn't seem to have that problem

Comment: Just tried with _sd_, same issue. Tried piping _fzf_ output to `sd -p "(\(|\)| |')" '\$1'`, but only blank space get escaped.